# Convert string with 5+ decimals to int

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm having issues with converting a string that has at least 5+ decimals to an int. 
It can look like this

`var amount = "113.000000000000";`, my result I'm looking for is `113`

I have tried a bunch of diferent converts without having any luck.

I do have a solution now that works, it is a extended method and maybe it's not so good solution

```
var amount = "113.000000000000";                
if (amount.Contains("."))
{
    var index = amount.IndexOf('.');
    return int.Parse(amount.Substring(0, index));
}
```

thanks for input

**EDIT**
I have this as suggested, but as I mention it's formatException

```
var t = availibleQuantity.InnerText;
var test = (int) float.Parse(t.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: What if the string is "113.000000000001"?

Comment: never gone be it's always 0 decimals. I should add I have no controll over the value I get, It's deilverytime in days so it can't be `12.1` ect.

Comment: Why not `(int)float.Parse(amount)` ?

Comment: Then what is wrong with the solution you have now then?

Comment: In real life, things that are expected to never happen will happen frequently ;)

Comment: your code works in LinqPad. It returns 113. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know but in this particular situation it can't be other then that result ;).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hey, it is never expected that Nicholas Cage will ever make a good movie again, are we on to something here? Will it happen again. Did you just solve one of life greatest mysteries?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Well I'm not sure my main consern is performance, it's gone be used frequently, so any millisecond counts. What do you think would be best to do?

Comment: @Serv: I guess he is asking more of a code review, "maybe it's not so good solution". I would ask for migration to Code Review.

Comment: @mas.morozov throws an FormatException, input is in a invalid format

Comment: No I don't think so Jean. He says he has tried this without luck, so my conclusion is, he's running into culture issues because . and , as the delimiter.

Comment: @JeanHominal both yes and no. mainly I would like to know how to parse that string to a int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution

```
int m = int.Parse(amount.Split('.')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `NumberStyles` Enum in your `int.Parse` call, like this:

```
var amount = "113.000000000000";
return int.Parse(amount, NumberStyles.Float);
```

Note that you have to add `using System.Globalization;` and that there are other [NumberStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(amount)));